# Permanently adding permissions to view a users feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

In the documentation for facebook API, it states:

"Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post. Then your app can read:
  Timeline posts from the person who gave you the permission.
  The posts that other people made on that person Timeline.
  The posts that other people have tagged that person in.
If you attempt to read data from a feed that your app has not been authorized to access, the call will return an empty array."

What I want to do is add a particular users feed permanently to my app. I am not understanding how this works. Will this user need to be consistently logged in for the app to have access to the data or is there a way to permanently add the permissions for the app to access the data?

Comment: Store the accesstoken when you get it. The accesstoken will have the permissions that you asked for when the user logged in

Comment: The access token stays good indefinitely? 

Here is an example, I'm creating this app to always show my personal feed. If I log in and the app then has permissions and I log out then have another user logging in, they will still be able to see the feed?

Comment: If you store your accesstoken you can use it until it expires. Default is 2 hours but you can extend it to be valid for 60 days